# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 14]

Tags: python, valueerror

Here is what I currently have, but I keep getting an error message. Any suggestions?

```
Predictors = pd.DataFrame(['house_age'],['Distance_to_MRT_Station'],['Convenience_Stores'])
X=Predictors
y=('Price_Per_Sqft')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
LinearRegression()
```

This is the error message I keep getting, unsure how to fix it.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-172-040724a8c0e4> in <module>
----> 1 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)
      2 lr = LinearRegression()
      3 lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
      4 LinearRegression()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    330     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    331     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 332         raise ValueError(
    333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
    334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 14]
```

I tried to rename the variables but I still keep getting the error message.

Comment: `y=('Price_Per_Sqft')` is your problem

Comment: I fixed that n it still isn't working